# Footnote/Endnote references before or after punctuation? (comma, full stop/period, semi-colon...)

Tags: typography, typesetting

Simple question: what's the convention (or, if there's disagreement, guiding principles) for where to place reference, footnote and endnote numbers that apply to a clause leading up to a punctuation mark such as a comma or full stop/period?

E.g. in this example, should it be like [1] and [2], or like [a] and [b]?

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<sup>[1]</sup>, consectetur adipisicing elit,<sup>[a]</sup> sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua<sup>[2]</sup>. Ut enim ad
>   minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
>   aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<sup>[b]</sup>

Before the punctuation looks seriously ugly, but after can make there seem to be a disconnect between the reference and what it refers to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to be refreshingly clear and simple. The note reference characters go after the punctuation mark, like [a] and [b] above, unless it's a spacing punctuation mark like a dash. Seems to be pretty universally agreed.

Here's what the esteemed [Chicago Manual Of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org) (*subscription required, so, second-hand quote, from 14th ed. 1993, Clause 15.8, p. 494)* says about the matter:

> The superior numerals used for note reference numbers in the text
>   should follow any punctuation marks except the dash, which they
>   precede. The numbers should also be placed outside closing
>   parentheses.

As far as I can tell, the only disagreement with this convention is the optional preference by some to add kerning rules that pull the reference note back to overhang over low-hanging punctuation marks (commas and full stops/periods), presumably to reduce the 'disconnect' I mentioned in my question. Looks great, pain to do.

---

Common sense note: take care to avoid there being a space between the punctuation mark and reference. This also means: take care that the note reference doesn't break over new lines separately to the preceding content. For example, do...

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,[a] consectetur adipisicing 
elit,[b] sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore 
aliqua[c] - fugiat nulla pariatur.
```

...not...

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,[a] consectetur adipisicing elit,
[b] sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore aliqua
[c] - fugiat nulla pariatur.
```

---

Actually, there's one exception where I can't find a convention - ellipses. But that's such a niche unlikely case it's more of [a separate question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15346/footnote-endnote-reference-characters-before-or-after-an-ellipsis).

Comment: This is exactly how I've been handling it for 15+ years of typesetting.

Comment: IMHO, it is not "visually nice" to remove the space between the last word and the citation! You can use a non-breaking space instead (~ in LaTex). For example~[citation]. Thanks to [Daniel](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34414/should-you-put-citations-before-or-after-interpunction#comment68266_34414).

Answer (score 10):

In German language the rule is very simple:

- If the footnote or endnote refers to a single word, the footnote sign must directly follow the word. So your note [1] and [2] refers only to the words "amet" and "aliqua".
- If the footnote or endnote refers to a complete sentence the footnote sign must directly follow the punctuation of the sentence. So your note [b] refers to the complete sentence before. In German I never saw a footnote [a] refering to the half sentence before the comma. I do not know whether it is allowed in English.

To summarize: the position of the footnote sign depends on the point you want to refer.

Please keep in mind that the footnote sign has to follow the word or sentence without a blank (directly). In German footnote signs have no brackets, so you will only find a superscript number or a sign like dagger etc.